Using Drivers to Limit a Geo Node Input via Collection Instance Count
If the title sounds confusing then thats because the approach might be illogical to someone who understand this more than me.
I want to swap out the mesh of an object with some other objects/instances mesh's I have in a collection.
To do this, I have an input for the collection holding those objects, and an 'Index' integer input, to cycle through them.
I have the actual Index input, of the geo node, controlled through a Property (from the 'Item' category, of the 3D Viewport 'N' menu).
This is where Drivers come into play.
Now I am trying to dissalow, the integer UI input of the property to (for the lack of better words) 'tick over'.
So that if for example the max instance count in the collection is 4, and the user happens to click on the right arrow from 4 to 5, that it resets that counter to 4.
If that makes sense.
My attempt so far, has been to try and make the Property be a 'driver' to itself, and use an if/else statement with self reference to determine what the value should be.
This didnt work.
Is this even possible? If so, how?
Property Driver:

Geo Node Driver:
(-1 because min value is set to 1, but index starts at 0)

Geo Node Setup:


What im trying to do is change the value of the property, since when you create it it doesnt seem to let you actually change its limits (i.e. Max/Min) through external means.
Maybe Alternatively, instead of limiting the UI input property, would it be possible to do this via the geo-nodes?

Would I be able to do something similar with python instead?

You can use math node to clamp the input by value driven by driver:


Not sure if my approach to that is correct, since this doesnt seem to work, and keeps on swapping meshes when its past the 4 types of instances. Cycling over from the beginning.
Video of that here (imgur isnt working so temp link).
